# Spring MVC. Could not autowire for service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Делаю тесты для своего приложения на спринг, тестирую контролелер, не понимаю в чём ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.

User service:

```
public interface UserService {

User register(User user);

User findByUsername(String username);

User update(User newUser, User oldUser);
}
```

User service impl:

```
@Service("userService")
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(
        final UserRepository userRepository,
        final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}
//далее просто перегрузка методов
```

Сам тест для контроллера:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestUserRestController {

@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private UserService userService; // вот тут выдаёт ошибку

@Test
public void getByUserNameTest() throws Exception {
    User testUser = new User();
    testUser.setUsername("testLogin");
    testUser.setLastName("testLName");
    given(this.userRepository.findByUsername(any()))
            .willReturn(testUser);
    User user = userService.findByUsername(testUser.getUsername());
    assertEquals("testLName",user.getLastName());
}
}
```

В строке теста "@Autowired private UserService userService;" выдаёт ошибку:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'UserService' type found.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело?

Comment: можно код всего проекта посмотреть?

Comment: Таки да, вот это выглядит явно лишним: `private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  да, его там не должно быть, это я сам пытался хоть что-то исправить, поправил исходный вопрос.

Comment: я поменял _@Awtovired_ на _@MockBean_ и это работает, но я не уверен, что это правильно

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить имя бина для связывания (внедрения зависимости). Над классом сервиса и далее над тем полем (в контроллере), куда этот бин надо внедрить.

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Qualifier("userService")
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
. . .
```

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserService userService;
```

Но лучше это делать через конструктор:

```
UserService userService;

@Autowired
public TestUserRestController(@Qualifier("userService") UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Comment: 1) '@Qualifier' not applicable to constructor
2) Could not autowire. No beans of 'UserServiceImpl' type found. 
Что-то не работает

Comment: Cannot find bean with qualifier 'userService'